# How to get Email alert ID in salesforce flow

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

I have created a classic email template and an email alert. Added that email alert in the record triggered flow. I have to add that email alert to the case record. How can I get that email alert ID so I can add that to the case record?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Essentially you need to perform a "Get" step that finds the most recent EmailMessage object created (return only first record, sort by CreatedDate Descending), where the ParentId field is the Case Id you're referencing in the flow.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply! Listen again! I have created a case and a return order is created along with the case. I have created an email template and merged the return order number on the email template. When a case is created I have to send an email(classic email template) to the web email of the case. and have to attach that email to the case feed item. The issue is email template is forming at that time when case and RO is been created and we don't have the ID of that email template. So there is an issue in attaching that email to the case record.

Comment: Thank you for the extra details, that makes it a bit more clear - would you mind showing the flow itself?  If the issue is attaching the email to the case record, there's two objects involved - one is the email message, and another is a Task record.  Once I look at the flow I can give you a better answer

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jay. This is done now. Firstly I have fetched the email template then replaced all the merge fields by using the formula field after this I created an email message record where ParentId is record Id and took HTML value from the email template.